# Find particular solution of $y''+4y=12$ if the point $(0,5)$ has horizontal tangent line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Find the particular solution of $$y''+4y=12$$ if the point $(0,5)$ has horizontal tangent line (parallel to the $x$-axis).**

---

I know the general solution of $y''+4y=12$ is $$y=C_1\cos{(2x)}+C_2\sin{(2x)}+3\quad\text{for some}~C_1,C_2\in\mathbb R.$$ Now we have to find the particular solution but I don't know if the initial conditions are correct: $$\begin{cases}y''+4y=12\\\color{red}{y(0)=5}\\\color{red}{y'(0)=k,\quad\text{for some}~k\in\mathbb R}.\end{cases}$$ Are the $\color{red}{\text{initial conditions}}$ correct?

Thanks!

Comment: `k=0` isn't it?

Comment: @karakfa I think there are infinite lines parallel to the $x$-axis. That's my doubt. We must also have two initial conditions because the differential equation has order $2$.

Comment: I think the tangent line parallel to x-axis means that it's zero.  Two initial conditions are for $y$ and $y'$

Comment: @karakfa hmmm if the equation of the tangent line is $y(x)=y'(x_0)(x-x_0)+y(x_0)$ then if it's parallel to the $x$-axis then $y'(x_0)=0$. So we have $y(x)=y(x_0)$, where $y(x_0)=k$. $k=0$ is just a value, I think.

Comment: No, this $y(0)=k$ is given as $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the tangent line at $(0,5)$ is $$y(x) = y'(0)(x-0) + y(0) = y'(0)x + 5$$

This is parallel to the $x$-axis if and only if $y'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your general solution is correct.

At $(0,5)$ you have horizontal tangent line that is $y'(0)=0$

Thus your initial conditions are $y(0)=5$ and $y'(0)=0$

Comment: Ok, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your initial conditions are correct, except for the $k \in \mathbb{R}$ thing. You know that you have a horizontal tangent, i.e. a slope at $x = 0$, which is equal to zero:
$$y'(0) = 0$$

Comment: Thank you! How do you know that at $x=1$ we have a slope?

Comment: welcome .. i meant at $x = 0$, the slope is $0$, because we have a horizontal tangent

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$y_p=3$$ is a partcular solution.

the general solution is

$$y=C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)+3$$

a horizontal tangent at $(0,5)$ mean that

$$y(0)=5$$
and
$$y'(0)=0$$

these conditions give
$$C_1=2$$
and
$$C_2=0.$$

Comment: Good hint! That's much faster than write the system of equations to find $C_1$ and $C_2$.